# Difference between criterion and logical expression in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I came across an interesting question regarding excel and I would like to know the theoretical background of it, google didn't help...

Lets say you want to sum the values of column B if the date (stored in column `A`) is this week. So what you do is `=SUMIF(A:A;">"&TODAY()-8;B:B)`
I am interested in the explanation why there is a need for the `" "` and the `&` symbols.

If I use an if function, there is no need, eg.: `=IF(A3>TODAY()-8;TRUE;FALSE)` works perfectly.

So why is it that
`=SUMIF(A:A;>TODAY()-8;B:B)` ----> formula parse error
`=IF(A3>TODAY()-8;TRUE;FALSE)` ---> works

I noticed that the `IF` function requires a "logical test", while a `SUMIF` function requires a "criteria", but **what is the difference between a criteria and the logical expression theoretically, how can I explain why this is necessary to use?** (other than "just because excel works this way...)

Comment: SUMIF use strings so `>TODAY()-8` needs to be `">" & TODAY()-8`

Comment: Thanks! But if it is a string, how can it still define relations like bigger than or smaller than?

Comment: You need to quote the operator in sumif(s)/countif(s)/etc because it is a standalone parameter, not part of a longer equation. By itself, `>TODAY()` cannot standalone but `A1>TODAY()` can. For sumif(s)/etc, excel strings together the cell from the range and the string representing the resolved criteria and evaluates the concatenated formula. The `=` operator is the default so it can be added (in quotes) or not.

Comment: Great thank you very much this explains it so well!:)

Answer (score 0):

The majority of the question appears answered by a comment from @Jeeped

Excel is looking for specific information for each of these parameters. First, I would recommend you familiarize yourself with [Excels operators](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/calculation-operators-and-precedence-36de9366-46fe-43a3-bfa8-cf6d8068eacc) a little bit.

```
=IF(logical_test, [value_if_true], [value_if_false])
```

In this, we are looking for a Boolean expression from the logical test. Something to resolve to either true or false, with possible actions for either scenario. So comparison operators would fit naturally in there.

```
=SUMIF(range, criteria, [sum_range])
```

In this function excel is doing a direct comparison of the criteria to values existing in the range. If the criteria is true, then add to the sum array and move to the next. Once all true statements are found, sum them all and provide the result. So a comparison within the criteria doesn't work as the function is already doing a comparison of the criteria to the range.

The difference here, is the logical test in the IF statement must resolve to true or false and it is not expecting a string. The criteria in the SUMIF statement must exist as a value within the range to be summed. So the criteria must resolve to a value that exists within a range. This is done by interpreting the SUMIF criteria as a string to compare it to a ranges value string.

Why then is the quote and ampersand needed?

It boils down "just because excel works this way..."

Or, more specifically, quotes and ampersands are part of the basic syntax and operations of excel itself.

Or, in a totally non-technical sense:

Excel operators are like problem children. They always need both hands held. Always something on the left and right. They don't like leaving a hand free.